# Iverilog test cases

Tags: verilog, testing

I am working with testing certain test cases with iverilog with -o option
for example

```
iverilog -o <output file name> <Test bench if required> <verilog file>
```

I had also read about the other flags like -c -s and others given on [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iverilog), but i didn't get any test cases to test them.I am pretty new to verilog.So if any one can provide small test cases for iverlog to check other flags.

Comment: The manual may answer your questions if you haven't already checked http://iverilog.wikia.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags

Comment: @trav1s: yes i had already checked that link but didn't find it that much useful.Searching for more.

Answer (score 1):

After studying further i found that -c   option can be used even for two files i.e. testbench.v and verilog.v.

we just need to create a ".txt" file with the name of the both the files written line after line like this

testbench.v
verilog.v

and pass it to iverilog.Further i wasn't able to get any test case with the usability of -s  flag, though i tried to use  it in followoing case but it gives no result and give wrong .vvp file which after executing produce no .vcd file.

```
module half_adder(
    output S,C,
input A,B
    );
xor(S,A,B);
and(C,A,B);

endmodule



module full_adder(
    output S,Cout,
    input A,B,Cin
    );
wire s1,c1,c2;
half_adder HA1(s1,c1,A,B);
half_adder HA2(S,c2,s1,Cin);
or OG1(Cout,c1,c2);

endmodule


module ripple_adder_4bit(
    output [3:0] Sum,
    output Cout,
    input [3:0] A,B,
    input Cin
    );
wire c1,c2,c3;
full_adder FA1(Sum[0],c1,A[0],B[0],Cin),
FA2(Sum[1],c2,A[1],B[1],c1),
FA3(Sum[2],c3,A[2],B[2],c2),
FA4(Sum[3],Cout,A[3],B[3],c3);

endmodule
```

i used -s option with half_adder and as well as with ripple_adder_4bit but in both cases it didn't worked out.Still figuring out their use.

For reference i had used [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iverilog)